# Can I point a .org domain name to a private IP address?

Tags: iis, ip, domain-name, intranet, private

I purchased a .org domain from network solutions and I was thinking about using it for a intranet website running IIS6. I don't want this to be a public facing website. How would I set this up?

Comment: What operating system are you running?  If it's Windows Server, it has a DNS server built in; otherwise you'll need to install one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By my understanding, you didn't even need to purchase it. If the site is intranet, you could just set up a DNS server to point LAN computers from any domain to any server. On my LAN, I can point http://google.com to my file share.

Comment: I came here to post this.  Internal DNS is just that...internal.  Do you have an internal DNS server?

Comment: Yes i have to domain controllers

Comment: @djshortbus: Domain controllers do not *always* serve DNS. Is the DNS role installed and active on your Domain Controllers?

Comment: under the dns settings i don't know how to point the domain name to an IIS website on another server with the ip of 192.168.192.113

Comment: yes my domain controllers have DNS settings... i see an option to add a new zone is that what i need to do?

Comment: @djshortbus: Yes, create a new zone using the .org domain you own.  Create new Host "A" record(s) in that zone to point the name(s) to the desired IP(s).

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can point any domain name to a private IP address.  It will only be accessible from the inside.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can point ANY host entry in a DNS configuration to ANY IP address.

Specific, you an do it unless your host blocks it (for example by checking it in an editor), but that is not a DNS intrinsic limitation (and one that is arguable - makes possibly sense "unless user overrides it" to avoid stupid mistakes by users with less knowledge.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation online that will help me out with this process 
Thanks

Comment: Standard DNS documentation? MS has decent documentation, but otherwise get a book on how DNS works ;)